# easy pie chart not appearing in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, easypie

I am using NPM  [ng2modules-easypiechart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2modules-easypiechart)  for ionic project

Import the module  app.maodule.ts

```
import { EasyPieChartModule } from 'ng2modules-easypiechart';
imports: [
  EasyPieChartModule
]
```

I am using the easyPieChart directive in my component template but the chart is not appearing.

**Html**

```
<easy-pie-chart [percent]="percent" [options]="options"></easy-pie-chart>
```

**Component**

```
import 'easy-pie-chart/dist/easypiechart.js';

@Component({
   selector: 'page-transactiontype',
   templateUrl: 'TransactionDetails.html'
})
export class TransactionDetails {
  public percent: number;
  public options: any;

  constructor() {
     this.percent = 80;
     this.options = {
       barColor: '#ef1e25',
       trackColor: '#f9f9f9',
       scaleColor: '#dfe0e0',
       scaleLength: 5,
       lineCap: 'round',
       lineWidth: 3,
       size: 110,
       rotate: 0,
       animate: {
          duration: 1000,
          enabled: true
       }
     };
   }
 }
```

Comment: How can your `@Component` be empty?

Comment: updated @Component

Comment: Your naming convention seems wrong. Your selector is `page-transationtype` your templateUrl is `TransactionDetails.html` .. which could still be fine i guess but your component is called `MyComponent`. Is it declared as `MyComponent` in your declarations?

Comment: naming convention updated still not working,, import chart " import 'easy-pie-chart/dist/easypiechart.js'; "  this  is correct, no error in console

Comment: html <easy-pie-chart> component not working

Comment: I dont think you need an import in your component file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139138/discussion-between-sridharan-and-gerdi).

Comment: check your `package.json` to make sure the it exists in your `dependencies` on the npm page it should be `npm install --save ng2modules-easypiechart`

Comment: checked  exists in dependencies

Comment: error : EasyPieChart is not defined